# Multiple criteria lookup function

Tags: excel

I am trying to find out whether local press releases may have affected companies' decision to join a certain government program. My Excel document contains A) a list of companies, B) those companies' postal code, and C) the date those companies got in touch with people from the program.

[image: Companies]

Secondly I set up a document that contains all press releases sent out by the agency in the past year. It contains the date at which a press release was published, and the minimum and maximum value of the Postal Codes of the area covered by the press release.

[image: Press releases]

I am trying to write a function that checks two things:

1. Is a company's postal code within the range covered by any press release?
2. Was any of the press releases that meet those criteria sent out within three months before contact was established?

If both are true, the function should return a 1 or something. If not a 0 of course suffices.

How do I do this?

---

In addition to Barry Houdini's proposal I've added yet another screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a formula approach, assumes Excel 2007 or later

For simplicity assume that both tables are in one workbook, 1st table is sheet1 and second is sheet2, you could then use this formula in Sheet1 D3 copied down

`=(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!D:D,"<="&B3,Sheet2!E:E,">="&B3,Sheet2!B:B,">="&EDATE(C3,-3),Sheet2!B:B,"<="&C3)>0)+0`

COUNTIFS can also be applied between 2 separate workbooks but both will need to be open.....

Comment: Thanks @barryhoudini. The formula seems to result, howevever, in a long list of zeroes... I've added a screenshot to my original post for clarification. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @daniel_ev. the postal code range is defined by columns D and E in sheet2, so my formula references both - in your screenshot the second range is `Sheet2!D:D`, that should be `Sheet2!E:E`